# The best distribution for processing things by fastest rate

Tags: calculus

I struggled with a good title for this problem, please let me know if you a better suggestion.

You have X website URLs that need to be visited and information extracted from them. Each website has a priority integer score 1-5.

You have Y information-extractors. They are all identical and process websites at a rate of 1 website per second.

How do you distribute the X websites across the Y information extractors to get the fastest overall priority/time rate considering all extractors?

For example;

You have 3 extractors.
You have 5 website URLs with priorities (5,4,3,2,2)

The ideal solution to me would be

```
extractor1 queue: 5,2
extractor2 queue: 4,2
extractor3 queue: 3

extractor1's priority rate 3.5 p/s (priority/sec)
extractor2's priority rate 3 p/s (priority/sec)
extractor3's priority rate 1.5 p/s (priority/sec)
```

With an overall rate is 8.0 p/s

My naive attempt/idea of solution:

Just looking at my example I believe the algorithm is as simple as ordering all the websites by descending priority, and then just cycle through the list of extractors, assign the website to each extractor based on decreasing priority

Is this correct? Is there a more calculus or mathematical way to determine this?